# Remove rows that are not duplicated n time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 4 observations per company (4 quarter). However, for several companies I have less than 4 observations. When I don't have the 4 quarters for a firm I would like to delete all observations relative to the firm. Any ideas how to do this ?

This is how the df looks like:

```
Quarter     Year    Company    
   1        2018      A
   2        2018      A
   3        2018      A
   4        2018      A
   1        2018      B
   2        2018      B
   1        2018      C
   2        2018      C
   3        2018      C
   4        2018      C
```

In this df I would like to delete rows relative to company B because I only have 2 quarters.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for Series with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible filtering:

```
df = df[df.groupby('Company')['Quarter'].transform('size') == 4]
#if want check by Companies and years
#df = df[df.groupby(['Company','Year'])['Quarter'].transform('size') == 4]
print (df)
   Quarter  Year Company
0        1  2018       A
1        2  2018       A
2        3  2018       A
3        4  2018       A
6        1  2018       C
7        2  2018       C
8        3  2018       C
9        4  2018       C
```

If performance is not important or small DataFrame use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Company').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion...you may want to `groupby` company and year because I would imagine the same company appears in more than one year.

Answer (score 2):

Using `value_counts`

```
s=df.Company.value_counts()
df.loc[df.Company.isin(s[s==4].index)]
Out[527]: 
   Quarter  Year Company
0        1  2018       A
1        2  2018       A
2        3  2018       A
3        4  2018       A
6        1  2018       C
7        2  2018       C
8        3  2018       C
9        4  2018       C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through your company column and check whether you have all 4 quarter results.

```
for i in set(df['Company']):
    if len(df[df['Company']==i)!=4:
        df=df[df['Company']!=i]
```

Comment: It's always better to use vector operations over dataframes than iterating through.